# PostgreSQL: Running SELECT DISTINCT ON ~700m rows - how to optimize?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, performance, clustered-index, postgresql-performance

I have a table that, if we look at just the relevant parts, has two columns: `id` and `raw_data`. `id` is an integer, and `raw_data` is a text blob. At this point, the table has no constraints or indexes except for an index on `id`.

My goal is to deduplicate (by `id`) this data and dump it all to plaintext files (on Amazon S3).

Note that any row with the same `id` can be assumed to be an exact duplicate (so I only need one, random row's data per `id`).

The table is on an Amazon EC2 RDS database with 2TB of space, 15GB of RAM. I can expand settings if needed, but want this to run over a reasonable time (i.e. max 24-48 hours, preferably faster).

The queries I'm trying to run (but are too slow) are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, data
FROM table
OFFSET <0 through end of table>
LIMIT 250000
```

The first few offsets run within a reasonable time, but quickly becomes unmanageable (at least minutes to return) when the offset hits 10m+.

Since starting, I've created that `id` index, removed all other constraints and indexes (there's other columns than I described, but not relevant), set `maintenance_work_mem` to 4GB (for creating the `id` index), and most recently tried making the `id` index a clustered index. But this happened:

```
cluster id using idx_0;
ERROR:  could not extend file "base/16390/46741.294": wrote only 4096 of 
8192 bytes at block 38558630
HINT:  Check free disk space.
```

[image]

Key questions:

1) Is SELECT DISTINCT ON with an OFFSET the right way to do this? Is there a more efficient query for pulling the data?

2) Is there anything else I can do to the DB/table to optimize? Would the clustered index solve my problem? Why is it taking over 1.1TB of extra space to deal with ~800GB of data?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is this a one-time operation (of writing these data into files)?

Comment: Yes, just a one time

Comment: I think saving (just the highest id of the last batch) and then using your query with `WHERE id > @last_high_id` and no `OFFSET` would improve efficiency a lot.

Comment: Or (similar but without saving the high id) use a condition like `WHERE id >= 250000 * @x AND id < 250000 * (@x + 1)` with an incrementing `@x` variable (and no `OFFSET`, no `LIMIT`). This could also be implemented to run in parallel threads/processes.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to ypercube's tip in the comments above, I was able to keep the time per chunk of the query constant, and so good enough for my one-off purposes. I'm now running:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, data
FROM table
WHERE id > @last_max_id
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 250000
```

Takes about 1 minute per query. My whole process will take about 48 hours, but that's good enough.

Could definitely optimize further with multithreading if better performance were needed.

I also noticed that using a cursor would have probably worked similarly well:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
      id, raw_data
FROM table
ORDER BY id;

FETCH 100000 FROM my_cursor;
FETCH 100000 FROM my_cursor;
FETCH 100000 FROM my_cursor;
```

The FETCH's ran for about 100s, 110s, and 90s respectively so I imagine that scales linearly as well.